# How to add ornament to your 3D model?

Tags: modeling, texturing

How to add an ornament to a model like a picture attached below?

I don't understand how to model the ornament (the ring) like it is in the image. How can I add an object with the same shape, plus the same level of detail?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the ring?

Comment: In this instance the artist is probably using a normal map to get the super fine detail, it looks like it was custom sculpted for this prop (not just tiling all over). They probably did use stencils though to apply the majority of them to the mesh.

Comment: @Jakemoyo you're right, but it's rather hard to know which ornament the OP is talking about; probably the ring? A simple torus with a small outer radius and large inner radius could do the trick (don't mind if I got the terminologies wrong) plus what you said.

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry that's a knife or dagger. i saw it here : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/khanjali-179c0756397044569f71a4460b8d4caf

Comment: @jakemoyo do you have any recommended videos to learn this ?

Comment: [This](https://pixologic.com/zbrushlive/zbrush-summit-top-tips-decorative-sculpting-for-stylized-character-armor-pablo-munoz-gomez/) video looks pretty good as well as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RByXIvjcS7U&ab_channel=SethThompson) one. I would just recommend searching "Sculpting ornamental detail" and check out as many techniques as you can, there are several.

Comment: oh that's in z-brush. i might try installing z-brush then

Comment: @ApasipepOyong Not necessarily in Z-Brush. You can do them in Blender too. There are thousands of free videos on YouTube, just try searching "Sculpting ornamental detail in Blender" or "Sculpting very detailed objects in Blender" and you'll find many.

Comment: @ApasipepOyong It's more about the principle, basically everything in that video you can do in Blender, it's just a matter of figuring it out. A ton of what I learned about poly-modeling came from watching 3DSMax or Maya tutorials. Learn the principles and you'll develop a skillset that doesn't go obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sculpting such fine details requires a lot of geometry to deform the mesh properly. A mesh with 1 to 3 million vertices should work well. However, the actual number depends on the size of your model and varies.

There are several ways to sculpt these floral ornaments.

**One way** is to use an image and a *Displacement* modifier. Start with a low-poly model. Create a UV map for it. Add a *Multiresolution* modifier and add a few subdivision levels to create enough geometry for the details.

Then add a *Displace* modifier and add an image as texture. The setup for the texture is below the modifier tab. Add here the image file. If you want to change the size of the displacement you can scale the UV islands in the UV editor. Make a copy of the original UV map so you can still use it later for texturing and texture baking. Then set *Coordinates* to `UV` in the *Displacement* modifier's setting, and select there your UV map.

[image: uv map]

[image: model, modifiers and texture]

If you apply the *Displacement* modifier, the displacement will be stored in the *Multiresolution* modifier, and you can change it in the *Sculpt* mode.

**Another approach** is to use the *Mask* brush to create the pattern of your desire. A sharp falloff for the brush can help to get a sharp outline of the pattern. In the *Mask* menu there are also the *Sharpen Mask* and *Increase Contrast* commands.

When you're happy with the pattern, invert the mask (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and use the *Mesh Filter* brush with the `Inflate` *Filter Type* to carve in the details.

[image: masking]

You can bake a normal map (from Multires) to reduce the number of vertices and keep the details.

Comment: wow! so informative! many thanks my man. i really appreciate it.